# Authentication for two different applications (.NET Core app and .NET frameowk app) via Identity server 4

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, identityserver4, .net-4.8

What I'm trying to achieve here is to authenticate to two different applications: a .NET Core app `App1`, and .NET web app `App2`.

Scenario: when a user is authenticated to my `App1` which is via Identity server 4 (`app1` is configured and it's working fine), this same user should be able to also authenticate to `App2`.

I'm trying to find the best approach for this scenario.

- Is it possible to do some configurations on identity server to do this?
- Is it possible to add libraries to my App2 so it can read token and get the user info then authenticate ?

NB: when deploying the two apps on IIS they run on the same environment, so it's possible to read local/session variables.